# How to use perf to analyze C project code?

Tags: c, optimization, perf

How to use perf to examine which parts of code run slowly? I came about these 
[Links](https://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/PerfUserGuide) but still I could not understand the data generated which is something like this!So how do i understand the reports of perf and data generated by perf annotate?[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clOxb.png)

Comment: Start not from "`pref annotate`", but from "`perf report`" to find hottest functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) may help. As osgf said, you want to look for the "hottest" functions and instructions, that are where your program spent most of the time. Then think on how you can improve those areas. Make sure you have debug symbols so perf report gives you a more understandable output.